# Relations imply element is identity

Tags: group-theory

> Let $G$ be a group, $a,b \in G$ and $a^5=b^3=1$ with $a^2=bab^{-1}$. Prove $a=1$.

I've been playing with this for way too long and still haven't gotten anywhere.
I have $a^{-1}=ba^2b^{-1}$ and $a^3=ba^4b^{-1}$ etc but not getting anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Hint :** Compute $b^3ab^{-3}$ in two ways to obtain $a^8=a$.

Comment: Thanks it worked